# How to break a string in Python?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I have a string like:

```
"sharenfs = rw=@20.20.20.0/24,ro=a.oracle.com:@10.0.0.0/24,root=a.oracle.com:@10.0.0.0/24:@20.20.20.0/24"
```

And need to break this string 3 parts, like below

```
a = @20.20.20.0/24

b = a.oracle.com:@10.0.0.0/24

c = a.oracle.com:@10.0.0.0/24:@20.20.20.0/24
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the string

```
string = "sharenfs = rw=@20.20.20.0/24 ... etc ... "
```

First get rid of the leading variable name and quality sign:

```
content = string.partition(" = ")[2] # Keepning all after " = ".
```

Here you have a string with three parts divided by a unique delimiter "," which means you can use the split function:

```
parts = content.split(",") # Split string by ","
```

Each part in the list `parts` will now be a string with two parts divided by a unique delimiter "=" so you can use split again:

```
a = parts[0].split("=")[1]
b = parts[1].split("=")[1]
c = parts[2].split("=")[1]
```

or if you want a compact code:

```
string = "sharenfs = rw=@20.20.20.0/24,ro=a.oracle.com:@10.0.0.0/24,root=a.oracle.com:@10.0.0.0/24:@20.20.20.0/24"
content = string.partition(" = ")[2]
a, b, c = [x.split("=")[1] for x in content.split(",")]
```

Comment: sharenfs is the part of the string. Please help me to get the output

Comment: code is still the same. just test above 5 lines of code with your original string.

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: You can skip the partition and go directly to `a, b, c = [i.split('=')[-1] for i in s.split(',')]`